# Can we save screenshots only during failure with Electron and Playwright automation testing?

Tags: automation, electron, playwright

```
const app = await electron.launch({
    args: ['--integration-testing'],
    executablePath: AppPaths[process.platform],
    bypassCSP: true,
    env: {
      CICD,
      ...process.env,
    },
    timeout: 100000,
    recordVideo: { dir: '/home/ubuntu', size: { width: 1420, height: 850 } },
  } as Parameters<typeof electron['launch']>[0]);
```

The problem with recording video is it is saved for every test case unnecessarily and occupies a lot of space.

Also, the recorded video saves in a directory without much provision of saving the file in appropriate test titles to refer to. So this becomes so difficult as it saves in random file format and is hard to debug.

We have the option of screenshots

[image]

Even that looks not configurable. And did not find any option to save the screenshots only on failure.

Looking forward to just screenshots to capture that too only during failure. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a config file called **playwright.config.ts** with this content:

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
};

export default config
```

You can check the dicumentation here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#record-video

Comment: Hi we are using testrunner to execute playwright test cases. Will this still help?

Comment: This is not supported with electron yet

Comment: Ticket details: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/12774

Comment: I see. With electron that has to be handled manually.

Comment: with electron when we handle it manually, we are saving for everything and we cannot retain just for failures and that's the problem